# c3p0's max number of connections doesn't work in Linux

Tags: java, hibernate, database-connection, c3p0

I have a java application that uses hibernate for O/R mapping and I also use c3p0 connection pooling that ships together with hibernate. The DB is Oracle.

This is in my `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">3</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idleTestPeriod">120</property>
```

This is how I obtain the hibernate session:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HibernateUtil.class);
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static String CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION = "/hibernate.cfg.xml";
    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure(CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION).buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            log.fatal("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex.getMessage());
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

But when I run `SELECT * FROM V$SESSION WHERE machine='xxx';` in Oracle the number of connections can reach 20, which is greater than `max_size`.

The max connections don't work in Linux environment but they do in Unix and Windows. Any setting in Linux that needs to be tweaked?

I'm also suspecting there is a cache of the application somewhere, as previously I set `max_size` of 20. I'm running the application in Tomcat 5.5. But I don't know of such an application cache in Tomcat.

Another info: I'm running Linux 2.6.9-34.ELsmp. `Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 3)`

Thanks.

Comment: It's a protocol mismatch. If you translate it into the protocol for binary load lifters, C3P0 will interoperate flawlessly, without running out of connections.

Comment: Kylar, can you kindly explain more? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess you have additional DB sessions opened not from your application. For example, there should be an additional connection - the one you're using to run the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Sorry Boris, I've changed my question. It actually works in Windows and Unix environments but not in Linux. Thanks.